# RHEL 5.5 - Need to refresh /dev/disk/by-label links

Tags: udev, disk

I've added a fibrechannel disk to a RHEL 5.5 server. The disk is present and shows under /dev/sdxx - But I need to give udev a kick and have it refresh the /dev/disk/by-label/LABEL links; this is where I do my mount points.

I do not want to reboot the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `udevtrigger`. That should replay all outstanding udev-tasks.

Comment: systemctl restart systemd-udev-trigger.service for kicking things in the nuts with systemd

Comment: @lkraav RHEL5 is old init style.

Comment: I had to use `udevadm trigger` because my system (debian) did not have `udevtrigger`. Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Comment: @MironVeryanskiy same with CentOS7 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you label the filesystem when you created it? If not, it won't appear under `/dev/disk/by-label` as it doesn't have one!

You don't mention which filesystem you're using, so I'll assume `ext3` as that's the default in RHEL 5. You can use `tune2fs` to examine the device:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep name
Filesystem volume name:   home
```

If this says `<none>` then you can use `tune2fs` again to add a label:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -L mylabel /dev/sda1
```

This should populate `/dev/disk/by-label`.

You can also use `-L label` with `mkfs.ext3` when creating the filesystem.